# How to remove \hbox error from the figure command in this code?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

Thank you for giving the time to go through my problem.
I have been trying to run the following snippet of my code for some time but it keeps showing the given \hbox error. After repetitive edits, the problem is not solved and the same problem keeps coming up.

What change should I make to the code so that image can be plotted?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached the images below for reference.(The marked line is line 157)

[image: Code Error][image: Actual Code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}                                                                     
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{c}
    \label{fig 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{\emph{System 1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{e}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{f}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{\emph{System 2}}
    \label{fig:1}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't make people try to debug an image, please always provide a complete small test file that shows the problem. The hbox warning isn't an error, you just have something too wide. The extra } is an error but without an example hard to say where. You may literaly have an extra } in your document or you may be using an obsolete package that has errors

Comment: Apologies for that @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: the underfull warning on line 126 is most likely a mis-placed `\\ ` command.

Comment: If I remove this code snippet then the rest of the code runs and underfill warning doesn't show. Also please have a look at the full code which I have recently edited into the question. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: You had only provided a fragment which could not be used to debug. I edited it to make a test document but it gives no error, please edit the example to show the `extra }` error, otherwise it is produced by code that is not shown. The overfull hbox is just that your images are too large, again that depends on your original image size which we can not see. Is it intentional that they are all scaled to 0.5 except one that is 0.55 (and that is the one that is too large)

Comment: You don't know the original size of `example-image`. Scaling it at 0.5 or 0.55 *might* or not fit in `0.3\textwidth`. Using `scale` is always subject to this problem: use a multiple of `\linewidth` instead.